# Error mgs: No value given for one or more required parameters: rgds to multiple parameters

Tags: c#, ms-access

Access 2003
VS 2010 C#

I am having problems with my WHERE clause. Initially I used the OR but now realized it must be something to do with the WHERE that I am not doing something right or is it something else? Please can someone help me here. Thanks in advance. ps c sharp student helped me previously.

StudentTable

> Field Name    Data Type

```
 ID         Number 
 FirstName  Text
 LastName   Text
 StudentDOB Date/Time
 Course     Text
```

connection string:

```
myCon = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\...\StudentDB.mdb");
```

btnFind method...

```
private void btnFind_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string title = txtSearch.Text.ToString();
        string queryString = "SELECT * FROM StudentTable WHERE ID = ?"; //I have also tried WHERE ID = @ID without success

        OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand();
        command.CommandText = queryString;
        command.Connection = myCon;
        myCon.Open();
        OleDbDataReader dr = command.ExecuteReader();
        while (dr.Read())
        {
            txtStudID.Text += String.Format("ID: {0}\n", dr["ID"].ToString());
            txtFirstName.Text += String.Format("FirstName: {0}\n", dr["FirstName"].ToString());
            txtLastName.Text += String.Format("LastName: {0}\n", dr["LastName"].ToString());
            txtStudDOB.Text += String.Format("StudentDOB: {0}\n", dr["StudentDOB"].ToString());
            txtCourse.Text += String.Format("Course: {0}\n", dr["Course"].ToString());

        }
        myCon.Close();

    }
```

My delete method is this and there are no problems(I thought you may like to know)...

```
 private void btnDelete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand();
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

        cmd.CommandText = "DELETE FROM StudentTable WHERE txtStudID = ?";
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", txtStudID.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FirstName", txtFirstName.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LastName", txtLastName.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@StudDOB", txtStudDOB.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Course", txtCourse.Text);

        cmd.Connection = myCon;
        myCon.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        myCon.Close();

    }
```

I tested sql query in Access without problems...

```
SELECT StudentTable.ID
FROM StudentTable
WHERE (((StudentTable.ID)=1));
```

**Solution Found**

I found a solution from this link, from stackoverflow of course....

[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6475547/getting-data-from-access-into-a-text-box-in-c-sharp-by-clicking-a-button?rq=1)

Thank you everyone for their valuable time especially Brad.

**Brad - here is the code**

```
private void btnFind_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        using (var command = myCon.CreateCommand())
        {
            command.CommandText = "select * from StudentTable where ID = @ID";
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("ID", int.Parse(txtSearch.Text));

            myCon.Open();
            var reader = command.ExecuteReader();

            while (reader.Read())
            {
                txtStudID.Text = reader["ID"].ToString();
                txtFirstName.Text = reader["FirstName"].ToString();
                txtLastName.Text = reader["LastName"].ToString();
                txtStudDOB.Text = reader["StudentDOB"].ToString();
                txtCourse.Text = reader["Course"].ToString();

            }
        }       myCon.Close();
                myCon.Close();

      }
```

I may not use OR clause actually - this will do.

Comment: So what's the problem?

Comment: @Melaine - problem is am receving error message "No value given for one or more required parameters2

Comment: Which part was it? `@ID` --> `ID`?

Comment: atID - worked. I used atID with your code and had no effect. For whatever reason I am unable to use  at symbol in comment area.  I will update at the top

Answer (score 0):

You don't add the parameters in your `Select`

```
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", SqlDbType.Int);
command.Parameters["@ID"].Value = int.Parse(txtStudID.Text);
```

Also, you have a lot of parameters in your `Delete` but only use one of them. Was that a transcription error or do `@FirstName`, `@LastName`, `@StudDOB` and `@Course` actually go unused? `@ID` only happens to be used correctly because it is the first one.

Comment: Are you referring to btnFind as well?

Comment: Yeah, this code should go after `command.CommandText = queryString;` in `btnFind_Click`

Comment: No. Output is for example on textbox named txtStudID I enter student ID 2 the out is showing...1ID: 1

Comment: @bucketblast Try again with that edit. I bet that is a data conversion issue. Make sure you are passing in the right datatype to your ID

Comment: same output. My datatype is Number for ID? I am not sure how to pass the data type unless you have provided above

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26058/discussion-between-brad-and-bucketblast)

Answer (score 0):

Your SQL query contains a parameter marker (the ?) but you never specified a value for it. Your delete method does it correctly (calling `AddWithValue` on the `Parameters` collection) but even there, you're adding way too many parameters to your query.

You need to become more familiar with OLEDBparameterized queries. You should start [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbcommand.parameters.aspx) and check out the examples.

Comment: I should also mention that the OleDbCommand object doesn't pay any attention to the names of your parameters, it only cares about the order you add them.

Comment: User enters a value of either Student ID, FirstName or LastName.

Comment: That's fine, but you need to tell *Access* what value they entered so it can find the correct records.

Comment: you mean this...cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue etc

Comment: @bucketblast how do you deal with the logic of deciding to use `ID`, `FirstName` or `LastName`?

Comment: @Brad - I wanted the user to enter either ID, FirstName or LastName and then edit the record. ID is PK

Answer (score 0):

Solution found as updated in bold heading solution found. I am receiving a msg saying I can close this thread tomorrow.